# Html DOM submit form and handle redirect to submit again

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, simple-html-dom

I use `simple html dom` and I submit a `form` but it **redirects** me and I can get the html **only** of the page where I submit *not* the results.

How I can acces the new page with submited content in order to submit on the new page the second content?

My code

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$reguest=array(
    'http'=>array(
        'header'=>"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'method'=>'POST',
        'content'=>http_build_query(array(
            'd1'=>'test',
            'd2'=>'test2'
            'd3'=>'test3'
        )),
    )
);
$context= stream_context_create($reguest);
$html = file_get_html("url",false,$context);
echo $html; //shows the 'url' not the page that I should get after submit
```

Comment: Please, follow this guideline to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I added code,my bad

Comment: Perfect :-) Now you will get more help.

Comment: You'll need something with more features than Simple HTML DOM. Some library that will let you interact with the page (like submitting the form). Have look at Goutte https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Comment: @Nima I give it a shot now

Comment: @Nima making a new Client will remove the sessions?

Comment: I need more details to understand your question.

Comment: @Nima I submited a form and I want to submit a second one on the redirected link that I found,how I do that keeping the sessions generated by first submit

Comment: I think it's better to ask this in a separate question so you can provide some code samples, so we'll have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Nima https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534705/login-and-submit-form-with-web-crawler