# Login and submit form with web-crawler

Tags: php, forms, symfony, web-crawler, goutte

So in web-crawler I pass and submit data like this

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'link');
$form = $crawler->filter('.default')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array(
            'login'=>'ud',
            'password'=>'pw'

));
```

But if I use `var_dump($crawler);` I realise that I never get data from the website after login because it redirects me and `var_dump` takes data from the page where I submited.

*I want after login to move to the new link to submit a form*

```
$client->followRedirects(true);
```

redirects me to the new page but I can't find a way to submit there because I can't select the form `nth-child` but doesn't work

I use **Goutte** and **php 7**

Comment: Have you tried this? https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html

Comment: @JasonRoman Yes but does it work with external website?

Comment: Depends on the site and what you're doing.  What's the body of the response that you get back?  If you don't follow a redirect what is the response that you get?

Comment: @JasonRoman My bad,it redirects but I can't filter to get the form,it is the first form but not even with nth-child I can't get it says unreachable field or null

Comment: So it sounds like you're submitting to the wrong form?

Comment: @JasonRoman I searched form in the body and the one that I want to fill is nth-child(1) ( the first) but I get Unreachable field

Comment: @JasonRoman unreachable field data and the first field is data[title] ,it expects an array? even if it is just the  name ?

Comment: Not sure - sounds like you're grabbing the wrong form and need to figure that part out first

Comment: @JasonRoman I am sure that is the right form but it should say  unreachable field data[title] but it says  unreachable field data

Comment: Now I need to click on an empty link to generate with ajax some inputs on that website,can I add elements or click empty links on symphony on external website ?

Comment: I suspect you may be trying to fill in the form in the wrong way. I also struggled with this before and had to do a lot of experimenting. Take a [look at my article here](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/testing-symfony-forms-with-complex-field-types/) to see if it helps.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I completed most of the inputs but there is an Ajax block that is generated after I click some empty links ( in the interface you see it  as a button but is a link) and that generates another inputs that I need to fill

Comment: I'm wondering if a headless browser is going to work in your case? I did a quick search, and I see there may be issues. You might also want to try Mink. I have [an article on that too](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/using-mink-to-perform-functional-tests-in-symfony3-framework/), make sure you follow it to the tee.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Thanks ,composer doesn't update for some reason so I used TestCase from phpunit that I downloaded and I get  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found  for some reason

Comment: Instead of `class MinkPetitionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` instead extend `TestCase`. For example use `class DefaultTest extends TestCase`

Comment: @AlvinBunk  I told you above that I used that but I get error that  TestCase was not found

Comment: Do you have the use statement at the top? It should be: `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Are you sure the visit functions is good? I get  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function visit() on null

Comment: Yes, you should really post a separate question on this if you are having issue with my article. Explaining what you've done and what errors you are getting. It may take a while to get it working. The hardest part was setting up selenium and getting it running properly. Selecting `use MinkSetup` should make the `visit($URL)` method work correctly.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Thanks,I created a new topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594403/deal-with-ajax-block-in-web-crawler-or-create-manually-inputs