# Deal with AJAX block in web-crawler or create manually inputs

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpunit, web-crawler

Based on Alvin Bunk article [link to article](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/using-mink-to-perform-functional-tests-in-symfony3-framework/) I want to create a web-cralwer that logins in a website then submits a form.

My problem is that on that website there is an Ajax block that generates after clicking and empty link few inputs that I need to fill so I need to click that empty link somehow or to insert the inputs manually .

I changed the code below in a lot of ways to try to make it work but on the visit function I got stuck

I get **Uncaught Error: Call to a member function visit() on null**

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

trait MinkSetup
{
    private $minkBaseUrl;
    private $minkSession;

    /**
     * @before
     */
    public function setupMinkSession()
    {
        $this->minkBaseUrl = 'https://www.url.com';
        $driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver('firefox');
        $this->minkSession = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);
        $this->minkSession->start();
    }

    public function getCurrentPage()
    {
        return $this->minkSession->getPage();
    }

    public function getCurrentPageContent()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentPage()->getContent();
    }

    public function visit($url)
    {
         echo $url;
        $this->minkSession->visit($url);
    }

    public function login($user, $pass){
        $this->minkSession->visit('complete url');
        $page = $this->getCurrentPage();
        echo $page;
        $page->fillField('email', $user); // Enter username.
        $page->fillField('password', $pass); // Enter password.
        $page->pressButton('Login');

        $content = $this->getCurrentPageContent();
        $this->assertContains('logout', $content);
    }

    /**
     * @afterClass
     */
    public function logout(){
        $page = $this->getCurrentPage();
        $page->clickLink('logout');
    }
}
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


class MinkPetitionTest extends  TestCase
{
    use MinkSetup;

    public function testSubmitPage(){
        $this->login('user', 'pw'); // Login first.

        $this->visit('full url');
        $page = $this->getCurrentPage(); // Get the page.
        echo $page;
        $page->fillField('form_ban_id', '1234');
        $page->pressButton('form_find_student');

        $content = $this->getCurrentPageContent();   // Get page content.
        $this->assertContains('<u>No Petitions</u> exist for Some User Student ID: 1234', $content);
    }
}



$client = new MinkPetitionTest(); //tried to get something to work
$client->testSubmitPage(); //same here
```

Comment: I updated my Mink article with needed changes for phpunit changes.

Comment: Hi there King. Do you have a copy of your AJAX code somewhere? I've got a Mink project ready to check into github soon, however, the whole point of using Mink is because of Javascript or AJAX; so I need to understand what code you are using. You could also post it on pastebin and copy the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your test class like so if you are using the latest phpunit:

```
...
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MinkPetitionTest extends TestCase
{
   ...
```

Can you try that first and see the result?

---

EDIT #2

Also, your trait file is incorrect. it should be:

```
trait MinkSetup
{
    private $minkBaseUrl;
    ...

    public function visit($url)
    {
        $this->minkSession->visit($this->minkBaseUrl . $url);
    }
    ...
```

Try that

Comment: Same Uncaught Error: Call to a member function visit() on null  in the visit function,I updated the code

Comment: Did you enter the code incorrectly? You have `$this->visit(full url');` but the parameters should be quoted, like this: `$this->visit('full url');`. See my EDIT #2 about the trait file. Make sure you are copying the code as per my tutorial. There should be some minor changes.

Comment: I just made an example with full url,the link is correct,the visit function doesn't work,also changed to use the private const but the visit will always be on null for some reason

Comment: Do you have other ideas about dealing with ajax block ?

Comment: Does your namespace match!??? Those files need to be in the `tests\AppBundle\Functional` folder; if not you'll get various errors. A little bit of troubleshooting on your side would help.

Comment: I removed the namespace but the call to visit is the main error

Comment: You can't just remove the namespace, you need to add the correct one. In my example `MinkSetup.php` should be located under `tests\AppBundle\Functional` and same as the file `MinkPetitionTest.php`, in that same folder. Then you run the test from the Symfony project root folder. Everything should work - I just tried it to re-verify.

Comment: Do you have this code on github? In all this project I didn't used X Windows or linux

Comment: Create a new standard Symfony project, e.g. `symfony new my_project`. in the my_project folder,under tests, create the folder `tests\AppBundle\Functional`. Then in those folders create the files I mentioned above. Copy over your custom login form and controller/twig code. You'll need to install the Windows phpunit phar. Run your phpunit tests as `phpunit tests/AppBundle/Functional/MinkPetitionTest.php`. Try running just the `$this->login('user', 'pw');` test first to see if that works. Or even just a simple `$this->visit('http://127.0.0.1/index.html');`. Try it first.

Comment: I went to the article again and created the folders but I get the same error,isn't any other way,I need to learn more in order to use this,I tried this not for symfony but for web-crawler to pass the AJAX block

Comment: Are you able to check `all` your code into github, and then maybe I can look at it?

Comment: That's not a proper checkin; You should have all your Controller code and Twig code in the proper directories. For example you should have the folders `app/Resources/views` and also 'src/AppBundle/Controller`. If I don't have your controller code and login form, I won't be able to give you any guidance. At least I need a simple login form, and some basic AJAX form code once login succeeds. The login accounts can be stored in memory to make it simpler.

Comment: I will learn more about about Controller and Twig part and make a new repo,forgive me I never used symfony.I need some time ,I'm sorry that I made you waste so much time